# Python 'textwrap' module not replacing all whitespace when using 'wrap' and 'fill' functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to output some text to the console using the Python `textwrap` module. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) both the `wrap` and `fill` functions will replace whitespace by default because the `replace_witespace` kwarg defaults to `True`.

However, in practice some whitespace remains and I am unable to format the text as required.

How can I format the text below without the chunk of whitespace after the first sentence?

```
Some title
----------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.         Duis sem eros, imperdiet vitae mi
cursus, dapibus fringilla eros. Duis quis euismod ex. Maecenas ac consequat quam. Sed ac augue
dignissim, facilisis sapien vitae, vehicula mi. Maecenas elementum ex eu tortor dignissim
scelerisque. Curabitur et lobortis ex.
```

---

Here is the code that I am using.

```
from textwrap import fill, wrap

lines = [
    'Some title',
    '----------',
    '',
    ' '.join(wrap('''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Duis sem eros, imperdiet vitae mi cursus, dapibus fringilla eros. Duis
        quis euismod ex. Maecenas ac consequat quam. Sed ac augue dignissim,
        facilisis sapien vitae, vehicula mi. Maecenas elementum ex eu tortor
        dignissim scelerisque. Curabitur et lobortis ex.'''))
]
out = []
for l in lines:
    out.append(fill(l, width=100))
print('\n'.join(out))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like this can be done using `dedent` and defining separate strings for multiline strings.

```
from textwrap import dedent, fill

lines = [
    'Some title',
    '----------',
    '',
    dedent('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ' \
        'Duis sem eros, imperdiet vitae mi cursus, dapibus fringilla eros. Duis ' \
        'quis euismod ex. Maecenas ac consequat quam. Sed ac augue dignissim, ' \
        'facilisis sapien vitae, vehicula mi. Maecenas elementum ex eu tortor ' \
        'dignissim scelerisque. Curabitur et lobortis ex.')
]
out = []
for l in lines:
    out.append(fill(l, width=100))
print('\n'.join(out))
```

Comment: you removed here the spaces at lines end, and you wrote `' \\` at lines end... That's way it works...

Answer (score 0):

`replace_whitespace` is not regular spaces `' '` - but only `'\t\n\v\f\r'`.

From the docs:

> **replace_whitespace**
> (default: True) If true, after tab expansion but before wrapping, the wrap() method will replace each whitespace character with a single space. The whitespace characters replaced are as follows: tab, newline, vertical tab, formfeed, and carriage return ('\t\n\v\f\r').

https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.replace_whitespace

Comment: Ah, thanks I missed that in the docs. Even taking that in to account, I still feel the behaviour is inconsistent with with is expected - why does other leading whitespace in the multiline string get replaced, but not on that one line?